# MongoDB authentication fails in Docker

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

My docker-compose.yml

```
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    volumes:
      - ./mongo:/data/db
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    restart: always
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: pass

  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    environment:
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME: root
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD: pass
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_URL: mongodb://root:pass@mongo:27017/
```

When I run `docker-compose up` it logs the following errors

for the mongo service:
*UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [mongo:27017] on first connect [MongoError: Authentication failed.*

and for the mongo-express service:
*"error":"UserNotFound: Could not find user "root" for db "admin"*

I tried adding `?authSource=admin` to the ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_URL but the error remains.

Comment: try using `ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER: mongo` instead of `ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_URL: mongodb://root:pass@mongo:27017/`

Comment: After adding the ?authSource , did you rebuild it like this ? docker-compose up --build to force a build?

Comment: Tried both with zero success. Still getting "error":"UserNotFound: Could not find user \"root\" for db \"admin\""

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is not running the `--auth` command when starting mongodb. The mongodb image does not run `--auth` by default and must be overridden using the `command` flag.

Similarly to your example the docker-compose uses Mongodb's environment variable to create an init user, so enabling authentication should solve the Authentication problem.

```yaml
  mongodb:
    hostname: your_hostname
    image: mongo:latest
    volumes:
      - ./mongo:/data/db
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=${MONGODB_USER}
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=${MONGODB_PASSWORD}
      - MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=${DATABASE}
    command: mongod --auth --port 27017
```